# Tableview row height for another tableview inside

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have a tableview inside a parent table view cell. When the child tableview gets its data and reloads, the height of the parent table view cell remains the same even though the child tableView has more rows.

Is there a way I can increase the parent table cell according to how big its child table cell is?

For example, int his photo, there are six rows in the child table view cell but the height of the parent tableview cell doesn't change so I need to scroll the 6 rows inside the small parent table view cell.

[image]

Comment: Why why why do you need to have tableviews inside tableviews?

Comment: @HarryJ The parent table view is the home screen where it contains summary of different features. For example, one feature can be someones to-do list and second feature can be their spendings. 

The tableview inside would contain the details of that todo-list (for ex: list of top 5 items that are due).

Comment: Why can't you use sections, or collection views? This would fix all your problems & more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was too intricate to put a tableview inside a tableview cell. So, rather, I created a view and made the UI like a table-structure so I don't need to worry about the odd errors that it brings.

I'm pretty sure the reason it didn't work because the parent tableview would render the cell (which isn't yet configured for the child). Therefore, the height would turn out to be the height of the inner tableview when no data exist. When inner table view fills its data, the parent tableview's height would not change because it thinks that its height was set.